# Pop up for web form doesn't with button and hyberlink

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

How to create pop up form for when u click any row from gridview .it will pop up a form showing the detail . I don't want gridview with any button or hyberlink .

Comment: can you show us your code please? which kind of popup are you talking about and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hate those hyberlinks.

Comment: Use bootstrap modal popup. http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/0fscmf3L/

Comment: Have a look on [jquery-ui dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will help you!.

add **AjaxControlToolkit.dll** to your bin folder and design your aspx page like this

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
<style type="text/css">
.modalBackground
{
background-color: Gray;
filter: alpha(opacity=80);
opacity: 0.8;
z-index: 10000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
<div>
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvdetails" DataKeyNames="UserId" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
<FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn" ImageUrl="~/Edit.jpg" runat="server" Width="25" Height="25" onclick="imgbtn_Click" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="UserName" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Designation" HeaderText="Designation" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Label ID="lblresult" runat="server"/>
<asp:Button ID="btnShowPopup" runat="server" style="display:none" />
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnShowPopup" PopupControlID="pnlpopup"
CancelControlID="btnCancel" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:Panel ID="pnlpopup" runat="server" BackColor="White" Height="269px" Width="400px" Style="display: none">
                <table width="100%" style="border: Solid 3px #D55500; width: 100%; height: 100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr style="background-color: #D55500">
                        <td colspan="2" style="height: 10%; color: White; font-weight: bold; font-size: larger" align="center">User Details</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" style="width: 45%">UserId:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">UserName:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblusername" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">FirstName:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtfname" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">LastName:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtlname" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">City:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">Designation:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesg" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" CommandName="Update" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" />
                            <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </asp:Panel>


Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            BindGridData()
        End If
    End Sub
    Protected Sub BindGridData()
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * from Employee_Details", con)
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        da.Fill(dt)
        gvdetails.DataSource = dt
        gvdetails.DataBind()
    End Sub
    Protected Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("update Employee_Details set FirstName=@FirstName,LastName=@LastName, City=@City,Designation=@Designation where UserId=@UserId", con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtfname.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtlname.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", txtCity.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Designation", txtDesg.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", Convert.ToInt32(lblID.Text))
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
        lblresult.Text = lblusername.Text + " Details Updated Successfully"
        lblresult.ForeColor = Color.Green
        BindGridData()
    End Sub
    Protected Sub imgbtn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ImageClickEventArgs)
        Dim btndetails As ImageButton = TryCast(sender, ImageButton)
        Dim gvrow As GridViewRow = DirectCast(btndetails.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
        lblID.Text = gvdetails.DataKeys(gvrow.RowIndex).Value.ToString()
        lblusername.Text = gvrow.Cells(1).Text
        txtfname.Text = gvrow.Cells(2).Text
        txtlname.Text = gvrow.Cells(3).Text
        txtCity.Text = gvrow.Cells(4).Text
        txtDesg.Text = gvrow.Cells(5).Text
        Me.ModalPopupExtender1.Show()
    End Sub
```